# How to show GeoStatistical Analyst Layer in web map using ArcGIS Javascript API?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geostatistical-analyst

I have created a "GeoStatistical Analyst Layer" with "Diffusion Interpolation with Barriers" tool and then I published it on the ArcGIS for Server.

How can I show this layer in my web map application using Javascript API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [list of layer types that dynamic map service supports](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Supported_functionality_in_map_services/01540000044r000000/), there is also support for Geostatistical layer. Which means you can access your dynamic map service that contains a Geostatistical layer without any extra processing.

Since you are on Esri JS API for ArcGIS, you would need to look for the sample that just draws a dynamic map service such as [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/map_dynamic.html). You basically need to declare a variable

```
var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Population_World/MapServer"
```

and point it to the MapServer REST endpoint of your service published which follows the notation `http://%machinename%:6080/ArcGIS/rest/services/servicename/MapServer`. You can find out what services you have and the URLs they have via a special application installed with ArcGIS for Server called [Services Directory](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000vn000000). You can access this application at `http://%machinename%:6080/ArcGIS/rest/services`.